# How to create a javadoc for 2 separate classes in the same filein eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I've a short file that comprises of 2 classes which I don't want to place in separate files. How can I create a javadoc for the file that lists both classes? Right now when I generate a javadoc it ignores the second class.
I tried placing

```
@see class2Name
```

in the doc comments for the first class, but that simply created a non-link to the second class's name.
What is the proper approach if my second class is in the same file, and isn't an inner class?
Thanks

Comment: Is one of your classes nested inside the other, or is it non-public?  IIRC, by default Javadoc will ignore non-public classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can javadoc the second class just like any other class, and documentation should be generated for both. If you are looking at the Javadoc view in Eclipse, make sure you link to selection (button with 2 arrows) and click inside each class to see its javadoc, or simply hover over the class name. Also, notice the `{@link ExpertImpl}`, which allows you to link to the second class' documentation.

Quick example:

```
/**
 * This is class one.
 * 
 * {@link ExpertImpl}
 * 
 * @author Me
 * 
 */
public class ClassOne {

}

/**
 * This is class two.
 * 
 * @author Me
 * 
 */
class ExpertImpl {

}
```

That said, it may be a personal preference, but I would recommend against putting more than one class in the same file. It makes your project less readable and complicates things without offering any real benefits. You may want to explore putting the non-public class in its own file, or nest it inside the public one, if it makes sense. Hope this helps.